# SSRS Parameter ordering when they have forward dependencies?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

Question: In SSRS 2005, I have 6 parameters:

```
Parameter_1
Parameter_2
Parameter_3
Parameter_4
Parameter_5
Parameter_6
```

They all have backward dependencies (Parameter_N depends on Parameter_(N-1) ).
When they appear in the output, they are ordered like this:

```
Parameter_1 Parameter_2
Parameter_3 Parameter_4
Parameter_5 Parameter_6
```

But I would need:

```
Parameter_1 Parameter_4
Parameter_2 Parameter_5
Parameter_3 Parameter_6
```

However, I can't rearrange the parameter list, because they all depend on each other, and the display ordering is determined by the list order of the parameters, which would mean the backward dependency becomes a forward dependency, which would be illegal...

Is there any way to achive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar, and there the conclusion was that it is only possible using a wrapper application such as ASP.Net.

[How to change the SSRS input parameters position in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483148/how-to-change-the-ssrs-input-parameters-position-in-report)

Comment: I know that this is possible, but it doesn't solve my problem. The report needs to run on SSRS in a 3rd party WebPortal solution, and not as a ReportViewer application in ASP.NET.

Comment: Marked it as answer, since it seems like there really is no other way. It doesn't really answer my question though, which means I'm screwed. "Credits" to MS for that.

Answer (score 0):

To change the order of report parameters

In the Report Data pane, expand the Parameters node. Click the parameter and use the up and down arrow buttons on the Report with CTRL Key. Data pane toolbar to move the parameter higher or lower in the list.

If the Report Data pane is not visible, click Report Data on the View menu.