# Adding a text box for report description before the report executes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to add a report description (text) near the parameters area, before the report is run in Report Builder 3.0? Essentially, when the users click the report, and right before they run it, I want to provide them with a small description of what the report does and what the parameters do. I can do that in the footer but it won't help, because the footer is only generated after the report has executed. Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the default SSRS interface. You'll have to wrap SSRS with your own interface to add this.

To build your own SSRS interface, you can use a few different methods, such as embedding a ReportViewer control in a Asp.NET application, or using URL access in an iframe. See [How to change the SSRS input parameters position in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483148/how-to-change-the-ssrs-input-parameters-position-in-report/3628726#3628726)

Of course, with Javascript and client side DOM manipulation, you probably could sneak your content into place, but it's not a supported option.

Comment: Any idea on how I would do this??

Comment: Updated with a little bit more info and a link.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you can't show a report if parameters are needed for it until those parameters are chosen.  If you don't want to provide default parameters another way to solve this problem is by actually having 2 reports.

In report #1 you put the parameters and the text box of instructions, but nothing actually using those parameters.

In report #2 you put the parameters and the actual report.

At the bottom of report #1 have a button, that just goes to report #2 passing the parameters selected.

I've used this technique to provide instructions on parameters when I want a quick-and-dirty solution (as opposed to a proper solution such as what Jamie suggested with embedding)

Comment: If the constraints are to use a vanilla SSRS server, then this is, I think, the better answer. It may be much more practical for many developers as well, with regards to time and effort invested.

Comment: Regarding not wanting to use default parameters - it may be possible in some cases to choose defaults for which it is known that no results will be returned, allowing for a blank version of the report to be displayed when the defaults are used.