# How to make multivalue parameter to be selected from drop down or type values in ssrs report

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis

How to make multivalue parameter to be selected from drop down or type values in ssrs report?

I have multivalue parameter in my report I want to make this parameter select from dropdown or type values for parameters?

Thanks for your replay but above link is not for my situation.
I have 1 Report which has 4 parameters  @StartDate,@EndDate,@Store,@Employee_ID
-- @Store is multivalve parameters and user can select from dropdown list.
--@Employee_ID is also multivalve parameters and user can select from drop down list.

Now I want to change this@Employee_ID Parameter  SO user can select from dropdown list (select all or few Employee_id)Or if user know Employee_ID he can just type (Type employee_Id 1 or more then 1)for that Employe ID and run the report.

Is this possible in ssrs?

Comment: Are you asking how to you allow the end user to both have check boxes and enter a selection by typing on their keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

[I assume you are asking about how to allow the user to enter multi-select parameter values with typing on their keyboard, and that you have the existing use of the multi-value parameters already set up.]

While not a duplicate of an older Stackoverflow question, the answers are the same:
[How to change the SSRS input parameters position in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483148/how-to-change-the-ssrs-input-parameters-position-in-report/3628726#3628726)

Basically, you can't easily change the default interface for SSRS parameters. But it's not too hard to create your own website or application to create calls to SSRS. Then you can create whatever UI you can dream up.