# how to Customize the Parameters Pane in SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

We are using SSRS Reporting Services with various filters. but it takes only 2 filters in single line, how can we customize the Parameters Pane in SQL Server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to do this in SSRS.

You would need to create your own page with parameters then call the report. It's actually a bit of work though.

[How to change the SSRS input parameters position in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483148/how-to-change-the-ssrs-input-parameters-position-in-report)